# Winsock program causing port exhaustion

Tags: c++, tcp, port, winsock

Going off a different post that helped explain the source of the symptoms of my issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1348102/windows-10-ephemeral-port-exhaustion-but-netstat-says-otherwise

I am having a very similar issue - except the problem is the program eating up all the ports is one I created myself.

[See the top 2 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuAaL.png)

See the top 2 results - 6072 ports used by one instance and 545 by the other - if I understand that result set correctly.

There are 2 instances listed as there are 2 instances running - this is a program that connects to a machine every 60 seconds, asks if it has information, retrieves it if it does, and then closes the connection.

It was written in C++ using winsock TCP connections.

Is there anything someone could suggest I modify to prevent this from happening?

Currently, after about a month and a half of the program running, we run into the issue of not being able to RDC into the server "due to a time and date difference" even though the time and date are perfectly in sync with the NTP server and the rest of the computers, and of course it will seize being able to connect to anything.

We can still connect to the server directly through IP address, but not hostname.

I haven't yet found any solutions to this other than rebooting the server.

The mechanism for connecting is a simple and primitive:

```
void Connect(string ipA)
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    Debug("Connecting to socket...");
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        Debug("Client: Error at WSAStartup().");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug("Client: WSAStartup() is OK.");
    }
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    u_long mode = (u_long)0;

    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    GPT_ATTRIBUTE_NO_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL;
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Client: Error at socket(): %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    iResult = ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
        printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n", iResult);

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipA.c_str());
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);

    // Connect to server.
    if (connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        Debug("Connection failed...");
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
        Debug("Connection successful.");
}
```

This method is called with the IP address supplied as a parameter and results in a successful connection.

After that, several request-response packets are sent using these:

```
void SendPacket(int iResult, SOCKET ConnectSocket, const char* a)
{
    Debug("Sending message to CW: " + (string)a);
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, a, strlen(a), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        Debug("Send failed");
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else
        Debug("Send successful.");
}
```

And

```
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
```

And once we're done with the particular session, we close the connection:

```
void ShutDown(int iResult, SOCKET ConnectSocket)
{
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    Debug("Shutting down socket...");
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        Debug("Shutdown failed");
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else
        Debug("Shutdown successful.");
}
```

There are a couple hundred lines of code that handles the data received, but those won't be relevant as they don't deal with any sort of network connection.

To say I have no experience with C++ would be an understatement, I simply slapped this together using basic MS templates until it worked exactly as we needed it and haven't touched it since.

So if there is anything someone can point out that I could change to avoid port exhaustion, I would be very grateful.

Just to add a bit of clarity - the program will ALWAYS connect to the machine on the same port. I have tried to bind the outgoing connection (from Windows) port to the same one also, but I have been unsuccessful - wasted many hours trying to get this 1 simple thing right, but I presume that would resolve my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are calling `shutdown` when you are done with a connection and if we consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-shutdown) for that we see:

> The shutdown function does not close the socket. Any resources attached to the socket will not be freed until `closesocket` is invoked.

Which I take to mean that any ports associated with the socket remain in use.

Further down that page, we also read:

> An application should not rely on being able to reuse a socket after it has been shut down. In particular, a Windows Sockets provider is not required to support the use of connect on a `socket` that has been shut down.

So, all-in-all, I would call `closesocket` instead of `shutdown` and then request a new socket from Winsock when you need one.

Comment: Although what you say is true, re-connecting new sockets in small amounts of time will still lead to port exhaustion over time.  You should either pool the connections and reuse them, or else if you must create new sockets then either extend the wait time between closes and reconnects, or else `bind()` the sockets to a given port and enable the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Makes sense, the second option is obviously a lot more convenient if I understand correctly what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Paul I've modified it now to call `closesocket` instead of `shutdown`.
Remy, the time between connections is generally 60 seconds. Would you say that's rapid reconnection that will still lead to exhaustion?
Also when you say `bind()` do you mean the outgoing connection from the server end? That is what I have tried to do before, but according to Wireshark it still used a different port each time. I don't have the code anymore that I used before, but I'll recreate it today and give it another shot.
I'll also look into `SO_REUSADDR` - its the first time I'm seeing that. Thank you both!

Comment: UPDATE: Added the following to my Connect method:
`int reuse = 1;
 if (setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
  Debug("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");

#ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
 if (setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
  Debug("setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT) failed");
#endif`
Now when I call the PS script to see established ports none are listed for my app only while the connection is still active (which only lasts 1 or 2 seconds)>
I'll let it run for a few weeks and see how it goes.

Comment: @Unknown OK, GL.

Comment: Been a few weeks now, and safe to say the issue is subsided - the list of in-use ports do not list any for my application and we haven't had any issues with RDC claiming time & date difference. Thanks again for the tips, `closesocket` and `SO_REUSEADDR` seems to have done the job!

Comment: Great stuff, and a tip of the hat to @remy there.

Comment: @Unknown "*the time between connections is generally 60 seconds. Would you say that's rapid reconnection that will still lead to exhaustion?*" - it can, yes. It generally takes a few minutes for closed ports to be released for reuse, unless you use `SO_REUSE...`. "*Also when you say `bind()` do you mean the outgoing connection from the server end?*" - no, I meant the client end. Clients bind ports, too. `connect()` binds a port implicitly if `bind()` is not called beforehand. `SO_REUSE...` on the client end is fairly useless without an explicit `bind()`.